# How to add this type of Indicator in fl_chart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, fl-chart

i have create this type of graph in my project

[image]

i have try and create graph but problem to create those type of indicator in my graph

i have integrate `fl_chart` package for it

this is my code i try it..

My result when i try

[image]

```
class _ReportChartWidgetState extends State<ReportChartWidget> {
  List<Color> gradientColors = [Colors.grey, Colors.white];
  bool showAvg = false;
  double minX = 0;
  double maxX = 10;
  double minY = 0;
  double maxY = 6;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.70,
      child: LineChart(LineChartData(
        gridData: FlGridData(
          show: true,
          drawVerticalLine: true,
          horizontalInterval: 1,
          verticalInterval: 1,
          getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
            return FlLine(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              strokeWidth: 1,
            );
          },
          getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
            return FlLine(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              strokeWidth: 1,
            );
          },
        ),
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          show: true,
          rightTitles: AxisTitles(
            sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
          ),
          topTitles: AxisTitles(
            sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
          ),
          bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
            sideTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: true,
              reservedSize: 30,
              interval: 1,
              getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
            ),
          ),
          leftTitles: AxisTitles(
            sideTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        borderData: FlBorderData(
          show: false,
        ),
        minX: minX,
        maxX: maxX,
        minY: minY,
        maxY: maxY,
        lineBarsData: [
          LineChartBarData(
            spots: const [
              FlSpot(0, 3),
              FlSpot(2.6, 2),
              FlSpot(4.9, 5),
              FlSpot(6.8, 3.1),
              FlSpot(8, 4),
              FlSpot(9.5, 3),
              FlSpot(10, 4),
            ],
            isCurved: true,
            barWidth: 5,
            color: MSColors.primary.color,
            isStrokeCapRound: true,
            dotData: FlDotData(
              show: false,
            ),
            belowBarData: BarAreaData(
              show: true,
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: gradientColors.map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3)).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey);
    Widget text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 1:
        text = const Text('0h', style: style);
        break;
      case 3:
        text = const Text('3h', style: style);
        break;
      case 5:
        text = const Text('6h', style: style);
        break;
      case 7:
        text = const Text('9h', style: style);
        break;
      case 9:
        text = const Text('12h', style: style);
        break;
      default:
        text = const Text('', style: style);
        break;
    }

    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: text,
    );
  }
}
```

if any idea to how create those indicator in my graph?

Comment: on `LineTouchData` try using `enabled:false`, it will always show the tooltip,

Comment: not show.. @YeasinSheikh